# Selling alcohol for industrial purposes

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol

I am not a Muslim.

I have heard that Muslims may not trade in forbidden items such as pork or alcohol.

Does this extend to alcohol products that are not for drinking such as industrial solvents?

Does it matter if the alcohol is theoretically drinkable but sold for a non-food purpose such as cleaning surfaces, fueling cars, or lighting lamps?

Comment: A better question may be, Is alcohol forbidden or its use in intoxicants? I know a lot of Muslims which alcohol is involved in their life, for medical reasons, perfume and cleaning equipment, but of course they don't drink it!

Answer (score 1):

```
              In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

According to Shia Islam, it is not Haram or impermissible to sell alcohol for industrial purposes. So, totally, there are diverse kinds of alcohols, therefore it depends upon its kind which would be deemed as the haram one or the halal one (which can have positive and permissible using such as industrial using...).

> شیخ انصاری، مکاسب، ص 3، سطر 23; (Sheikh Ansari, Makaseb, pg.3, line23)

As well as this, to the best of my knowledge if I'm not mistaken -- concerning the last part of the query --, the sort of alcohol in the Urf (custom) can be effective too. Namely, e.g. if X-alcohol in the custom is not famous as drinkable alcohol (albeit rarely someones drink it) but is well-known for its industrial consumption not as a normal drinkable alcohol, subsequently (AFAIR) it would be permissible to deal ... and vice versa.

Let's elucidate the issue with giving an short/simple example; and it'll be more clarified for you if you adopt the previous illustration with the following example: e.g., the fruit "X" is sold/bought as a normal fruit, but its leaf doesn't normally/customarily have interchange (albeit can be eatable in specific circumstances...). So, the issue of industrial/drinkable alcohol can be adopted with such example, namely the custom is significant in its circumstances about its impressibility or ...

**Sourse(s):**

[www.ketabkhanemelli.com](http://www.ketabkhanemelli.com/kotob/farsi/729/06.htm)

[www.islampedia.ir](http://islampedia.ir/fa/1390/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Alcohols are the family of compounds that contain one or more hydroxyl (-OH) groups attached to a single bonded alkane. [[Wikibooks]](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Organic_Chemistry/Alcohols)

Only alcohol which is sold for drinking purpose is Ethanol ( CH3CH2OH ). Others are highly toxic, and irony is if you accidentally drank Propanol, you will be given Ethanol.

Well, according Shaykh (Mufti) Taqi Usmani -

> ......  the ruling with regards to the various types of alcohol, the usage of which has become widespread and they are used in many medicines and perfumes, becomes known, in that if the alcohol is extracted from grapes or dates, then there is no question of it being permissible or pure. However, if the alcohol is derived from other than grapes or dates, then there is no problem according to the view of Imam Abu Hanifa, in that it will not be unlawful to use such alcohol (m, and perfumes and medicines made thereof) for medical or other lawful purposes as long as the alcohol does not reach the level of intoxication.... And normally the alcohol used in medicines, perfumes, etc. is not extracted from grapes and dates, rather it is derived from seeds, honey, chemicals, petrol, etc... (Takmila Fath al-Mulhim Sharh Sahih Muslim, 3/608)

And also it is permissible to use hand sanitizers, and etc.

Comment: Other alcohols are toxic, but people still get high off of them